# Use of context API

Tags: reactjs, react-context, createcontext

I have tried multiple ways. Watched many solutions above but still couldn't solve this issue. Can anyone please help me using context in my project.

**SearchContext.jsx**

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const SearchContext = createContext();

export default SearchContext;
```

**Search.jsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import { Box, IconButton, InputBase } from '@mui/material';
import SearchContext from '../Context/SearchContext';

export default function Search() {
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
    };
    return (
        <SearchContext.Provider value={searchQuery} >
            <Box display='flex' alignItems='center' justifyContent='center' paddingTop='20px'>
                <Paper component="form" sx={{ p: '2px 10px', display: 'flex', width: '50%' }} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <IconButton type="button" sx={{ p: '10px' }} aria-label="search">
                        <AccountCircleIcon fontSize='large' />
                    </IconButton>
                    <InputBase
                        sx={{ ml: 1, flex: 1 }}
                        placeholder="Search User"
                        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search user' }}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <IconButton type="submit" sx={{ p: '10px' }} aria-label="search">
                        <SearchIcon fontSize='large' />
                    </IconButton>
                </Paper>
            </Box>
        </SearchContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

This is how I have used. Is it correct ?
I have later on used it here

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ApiService } from '../../API/ApiService';
import SearchContext from '../../Context/SearchContext';


function NumberOfContestParticipated({ handle }) {
    const [contestCount, setContestCount] = useState(null);
    const searchQuery = useContext(SearchContext);
    console.log(searchQuery);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const ratingUrl = `https://codeforces.com/api/user.rating?handle=${handle}`;
            const ratingData = await ApiService(ratingUrl);

            if (ratingData && ratingData.status === 'OK') {
                setContestCount(ratingData.result.length);
            } else {
                setContestCount(0);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [handle]);

    return (
        <div>
            {contestCount !== null ? (
                <p>Number of contests participated by {handle}: {contestCount}</p>
            ) : (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default NumberOfContestParticipated;
```

But when I console log the searchQuery , it gives undefined value. What am I doing wrong ?

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import SearchContext from './Context/SearchContext';

ReactDOM.render(
  <SearchContext.Provider>
    <App />
  </SearchContext.Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the `NumberOfContestParticipated`  component is not a child of the `Provider` component and so the context remains undefined when the state changes. Also it seems weird to me that you are wrapping your application inside the provider twice, there is no need for that if you are wrapping the entire `App` component.

Check out [this article](https://dev.to/hey_yogini/usecontext-for-better-state-management-51hi) for more information on how to use context.

Comment: How do we make sure if its a child or not ?

Comment: Well, wrap your app component with it. Then every component further down the tree is a child.

Answer (score 0):

For Create Context set initials to the context

SearchContext.jsx

```
const SearchContext = createContext({
  searchQuery: "",
  setSearchQuery: () => {},
});
```

For set Provider use like This
create this in SearchContext.jsx and export it

```
export const SearchContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");

  return (
    <SearchContext.Provider value={{searchQuery, setSearchQuery}}>
      {children}
    </SearchContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Use of Context

Search.jsx

```
export default function Search() {
   const { searchQuery, setSearchQuery } = useContext(SearchContext);

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    };
```

App.js

```
<SearchContextProvider>
  <App />
</SearchContextProvider>;
```